# Error Storage.Objects.Insert insertObject = storage.objects().insert("mybucket", objectMetadata, mediaContent);

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Error cannot find symbol storage.

I'm following the sample code here:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert

But could a bit of help.
How can I initialise storage variable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is not that `storage` is not initialized. The problem is that it either (1) doesn't exist or (2) isn't in `scope`.

Comment: The line of code was taken from the URL of sample code, so it should exist. And it's in the main body of code, not in an if statement or anything, so it should be in scope

Comment: Add the rest of your code.